# Start over with count when new element start

Tags: jquery, each, counter

Now what i want is a counter that will start over when the new picture class start.
The outcome i'm looking for is

```
   <ul class="pictures">
    <li data-slide-index='0'></li>
    <li data-slide-index='1'></li>
    <li data-slide-index='2'></li>
   </ul>

  <ul class="pictures">
    <li data-slide-index='0'></li>
    <li data-slide-index='1'></li>
    <li data-slide-index='2'></li>
    <li data-slide-index='3'></li>
    <li data-slide-index='4'></li>
   </ul>

   <ul class="pictures">
    <li data-slide-index='0'></li>
    <li data-slide-index='1'></li>
    <li data-slide-index='2'></li>
   </ul>
```

i tried things like:

```
  $( ".pictures  > li" ).eq( 0 ).attr( "data-slide-index", "0" );
  $( ".pictures  > li" ).eq( 1 ).attr( "data-slide-index", "1" );
  $( ".pictures  > li" ).eq( 2 ).attr( "data-slide-index", "2" );
  $( ".pictures  > li" ).eq( 3 ).attr( "data-slide-index", "3" );
  $( ".pictures  > li" ).eq( 4 ).attr( "data-slide-index", "4" );
  $( ".pictures  > li" ).eq( 5 ).attr( "data-slide-index", "5" );
```

or

```
$( ".pictures" ).each(function() {
      var numberdataslide = 0;
        $( ".pictures li" ).each(function() {
          numberdataslide++;
          $( this ).attr( "data-slide-index", numberdataslide );
      });
    });
```

But everything i do, i wont get it.
Please help!

Comment: Replace `$( ".pictures li" )` with `$(this).find('li')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
$( ".pictures" ).each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
    li = $this.find('li');

    li.each(function() {
        $(this).attr( "data-slide-index", li.index(this) );
    });
});
```

**Edit:**

Even simplest solution:

```
$( ".pictures" ).each(function() {
    $('li',this).attr( "data-slide-index", function(index){return index;} );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I can think of is the following:

```
$('ul.pictures').each(function(){
    // i: the index of the current element among the collection returned
    // by the selector
    $(this).find('li').attr('data-slide-index', function(i){
        return i;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Yny22/).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: This is the cleanest approach!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `index` provided by [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/);

```
$(".pictures").each(function() {
    $(this).find("li").each(function(index) {
        $(this).data("slide-index", index);
    });
});
```

..and [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for setting data attributes.